# Get string characters until number reached

Tags: php, regex, string

Basically, I want to get the letters of the string from the first character until a number is reached.

Example

Input: asdfblabla2012365adsf

Output: asdfblabla

Comment: The regex pattern is `^\D+`. PHP usage is as explained in [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$matches = array();
$input = 'asdfblabla2012365adsf';
if (preg_match('/(\D*)(\d*)/', $input, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1]; // asdfblabla
}
```

Comment: Note that this regex will *always* match.

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = 'asdfblabla2012365adsf';
preg_match('/^([[:alpha:]]+)/', $s, $m);
echo $m[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

i have found a solution for you

```
<?php
$newStr = '';
$str = 'asdfblabla2012365adsf';
for($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++){
  if(is_numeric($str[$i]))
     break;
  $newStr .= $str[$i];
}
 echo $newStr;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string str,out;
    cin>>str;

    std::string::iterator itr = str.begin();

    while(itr != str.end() )
    {
        if(*itr >= '0'  && *itr <= '9')
            break;

        out += *itr;
        itr++;
    }

    cout<<out;
    return 0;
}
```